# Open Close Braces checking

Tags: c#, regex

I am checking open brace and close brace. assume this is my input

> {xyz{njdjd{lkdf}fj}jf}

when I compile that input open brace and close braces want to separate and stored in list for that I used following code

```
`List<Match> open=new List<Match>();
        List<Match> close = new List<Match>();

        MatchCollection openbrace = Regex.Matches(MELEdtior, "{");
        foreach(Match o in openbrace)
        {
            open.Add(o);
        }
        MatchCollection closebrace = Regex.Matches(MELEdtior, "}");
        foreach(Match c in closebrace)
        {
            close.Add(c);
        }
```

that's worked perfectly and I got two separate list with open and close brace.

Now I want compare both the list and pair the open and close brace. if any one open or close missed that pair means wants to show the error. for that I used for each loop. what I am facing means one open brace that check all close brace. but I want to check open brace with one close brace.

```
 if(open.Count==close.Count)
       {
        foreach(var openi in open)
        {
            foreach(var closei in close)
            {
               if( openi != closei)
               {

               }
               else { return "failed"; }
            }
        }

        }
        else{return "count failed";}

        return "";
```

what is wrong?

Comment: You need to revisit your approach. With the current logic, the following expression will pass :  }xyz}njdjd}lkdf{fj{jf{ . Is this expected?

Comment: no just guide me, how to compare one list item with another list item

Comment: See [this demo](http://ideone.com/9lVzTV) if you want to validate that the string has a balanced amount of opening and close braces. [Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*(%3f%3a%7b(%3f%3e%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d%7c(%3f%3co%3e%7b)%7c(%3f%3c-o%3e%7d))*(%3f(o)(%3f!))%7d)*%5b%5e%7b%7d%5d*%24&i=%7bddd%7bddd%7dddd%7d)

Comment: Use a for loop instead of foreach

Answer (score 0):

Single loop running both collection should solve your problem.

```
        if (open.Count == close.Count)
        {
            var listCount = open.Count;

            for (var i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
            {
                if (open[i] != close[i])
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    return "failed";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "count failed";
        }
        return "passed";
```